# What SQL query can I use to get the first record of each group based on a certain column?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

"I'm working with a database table in SQL and I want to retrieve the first row of each group based on a certain column. The table has columns 'group_id' and 'value', and I want to retrieve the row with the lowest 'value' for each unique 'group_id'. How can I achieve this using SQL?"

[image: table]

based on the example table above i would like to get just the name alex and brown

Here is what i have tried

```
SELECT * FROM tailors
                            WHERE id IN(
                                    SELECT min(id)
                                    FROM tailors
                                    GROUP BY cat_id,id,name,status
                            )
```

but i am getting all the record when i am just trying to get the first data of each matching category id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to take out id and name from your group by clause -

```
SELECT * FROM tailors
 WHERE id IN (SELECT min(id)
                FROM tailors
               GROUP BY cat_id, status
             );
```

Comment: thank i really didn't see that there

Answer (score 3):

If the logic remains same throughout the table, and the version of the DB is 8.0+, then use such an aggregation :

```
SELECT name
  FROM( SELECT t.*, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id) AS min
          FROM tailors AS t ) AS tt
 WHERE id = min
```

assuming `id` is a primary key column, there will be only one minimum value per each `cat_id`.

`GROUP BY cat_id` is handled by `PARTITION BY cat_id` and the other columns(`name` and `status`) following it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To return only one row use `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT * FROM tailors
       WHERE id IN(
        SELECT min(id)
        FROM tailors
        GROUP BY cat_id,id,name,status
      ) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: if i use limit 1 i only get the first data